# Как получить следующий номер WT.Part'а в Windchill с помощью API

Tags: java, delphi

При создании объекта `WT.Part`/`Wt.Document` автоматически генерируется номер (скорее всего что берется с сиквенса). Может кто то подскажет каким образом можно достучатся к сиквенсу и получить следующий номер `WT.Part`/`Wt.Document` с помощью API. При работе использую `Info*Engine` и `SOAP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как временное решение - создаю новый Part, считываю номер и либо использую его либо удаляю.

**Upd1**

Если использовать `Java` - можно воспользоватся методом:

`wt.fc.PersistenceHelper.manager.getNextSequence("SEQUENCE_NUMBER_OF_YOUR_OBJECT")`